# how to redirect my localhost as domain for my hotspot users

Tags: php, python, hotspot

Having hotspot and a [ php ] localhost, how to redirect every one how to redirect anyone once connect to that vertual host with specified doman [ ex: test.com ]

**note that this should work regardless internet is on or off, just hotspot generates a domain that servs as a localhost pass**

someone told me python could do so or hosts should help
[ I know how to set config to listen to IPs but not to host or redirect it ]

so if I have ip [x.x.x.x] how to make it accessable as a domain [test.com] and redirect all hotspot users to that vertual host

[ I need any free thing,
it's for studing,
If there is any way using hotspot setting, php configration, python or even any program that help ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I wanted is to have a dns record for locally in my Hotspot

I think I found what I'm seeking for

- [UnBound](https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/about/)
- [Local DNS with Unbound](https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2019/227/Local-DNS-with-Unbound)

Answer (score 1):

In your host file, simply add.

```
0.0.0.0 test.com
```

this will do the trick.

Comment: I tried [ 127.0.0.1 ] and didn't work what is the meanning of the line you wrote please [ is it differ ],, and thanks a lot for help

Comment: It's means your are using your IP globally, through this u can access your application from any device connected to your network

Comment: sir, I found another solution, but thanks